# updation of passbook through push notification

Tags: ios, passbook, passkit

Using production certification of passbook( pass type id) sending notification to passbook passes. Notification(push token) sent successfully but problem is.

1) Notification not shown in mobile.(It shown or not)

2) passees hit by this url after sending push notification :

https://webServiceURL/v1/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier

and

https://webServiceURL/v1/log

using blank payload and push token use as a device token

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notifications to Passbook via Urban Airship not appearing on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839943/push-notifications-to-passbook-via-urban-airship-not-appearing-on-device)

Comment: Web service provides a list of serials for all passes with the passTypeIdentifier that have changed since the lastUpdated tag

means

web service provides json  array of string(serials)

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do. The documents are very clear and the 4 of the 5 end points need to be implemented to provide a push update. You understand that you are supposed to provide the web service from your own server, yes?

Comment: Web service send the new .pkpass bundle

means 

pass.json

Comment: You put the url of your server into the pass.json and your server responds with the serials, and then if you receive a second request from he device for the pass, you respond with the new pkpass bundle.

Comment: pkpass bundle meand pkpass archive

Comment: Getting the Latest Version of a Pass( webServiceURL/version/passes/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber)
   Response

If request is authorized, returns HTTP status 200 with a payload of the pass data.


sir , what is payload of the pass data

Comment: The payload is the new .pkpass bundle

Comment: and header of this bundle

Answer (score 0):

1. It will show only when you specific "Change Message" to changed value
2. first hit is wallet ask server which serial number with deviceLibraryIdentifier and passTypeIdentifier has been updated. You must have code to return the information. I guess you already done it.

second hit is wallet found error from your data in the first hit and send the error to your server. So you have to check the payload to identify the error and fixed it.